# TwinCat 3 Software Protection Windows Login issue

Tags: twincat, visual-studio-shell

I am using Twincat 3.1.4024.47 with VS Shell

I would like to use the software Protection. I know the function from a previous project and I remember that I can use the Windows password.
When I use the Windows password, neither the user logs in by himself (I know this from the previous project). And even if I enter my password, the log-in does not work.

Even a thorough research has not yielded any results so far.

Maybe one of you can explain me the mechanism so that I can talk to my system administrator.

Or someone knows the problem and already has a solution

Thank you for your help

**Login popup:**

[image: login popup]

**Second login popup**

[image: second login popup]

Comment: Are you using the built function from beckhoff?

Comment: yes we only use Beckhoff functionality

Comment: does the window pop up? does it show you some users?, can you share us maybe a scrennshot? i have experience working with software protection in twincat

Comment: @DonMiguelSanchez i have added the Login Popups. The first pupup with my login and correct password selected via Dropdown. -> Hit OK -> immediately the second login popup comes up. 
I have also some experience with software protection. I think the error lies with windows, a missing entry or so.

Comment: it seems that the loaded user db has another password stored or you have to copy the correct database, check under `C:\TwinCAT\3.1\CustomConfig\UserDBs` if the correct user database is in this folder

Comment: It is the correct database in the right place with the correct user/password combination. When I create a new user without Windows credentials and a free password, it works. Only when i user the Windows credentials, it doesn't,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue causes on 2 issues.

First: I entered, under Name, my Email address. There should be domain-name\user-name.

Second: TwinCat replied with the output that “the user was found, and the password was set”.

[user editor popup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fakhm.jpg)

Under name, you should enter [domain-name]\[username]

If it doesn`t work lock at Windows -> systeminformation -> username what your full login is.